# How to verify if the user is logged in my extension?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome-extension

I have `popup.html` stored locally on my computer, and I have `login.php` on my website. After logging in on the website, a session called 'users' is started. In `popup.html` on my local machine, how does the extension know if there is a session in `login.php` and how can it check it? If a user session is started, it should proceed to the extension's `popup.html`. If there is no user session, it should redirect to `error.html`, which asks for login. `error.html` should display a link and redirect the user to `example.com/login` page and check if a user session exists or not.

Comment: `how does the extension know if there is a session in login.php`...it can't really, because it's not a PHP file. It needs to be renamed with .php and then you can run PHP code in it to check the session.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the extension"_?

Comment: `error.html, which asks for login`...surely `login.php` should ask for login. Why not just redirect there? That's what most authentication systems do when there isn't a valid session.

Comment: This whole architecture sounds a bit unlikely to work. It's possible you could make this work by using ajax requests from the .html pages to check the login/session status, but not sure it would be that easy to secure in a foolproof way.

Comment: I like ADyson's idea of AJAX calls. That's probably the only way to make this work.

Comment: @ADyson thats not the answer for my question please help i am stuck so hard

Comment: Why is it not the answer? Please explain why my suggestions would cause you a problem, specifically. Then we can understand what to rule out, and why.

Comment: [Link to my Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76598501/i-am-checking-login-with-ajax-but-it-keeps-saying-false) @ADyson please check